# How to select HTML element by XPATH if attribute name contains space?

Tags: html, xpath

for example

```html
<li big class="attribute"></li>
```

in selenium selecting would be like this

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@big class="attribute"]');
```

so how can i select the element by XPATH , using that results an invalid expression.
selecting just by class like this **//*[@class="attribute"]** doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select element by both attributes correct code would be

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@big and @class="attribute"]')
```

note that `big` seem to be a separate boolean attribute (it might not have an explicit value) but not an *"... attribute name contains space"*

Comment: Oh so they are 2 separate attribute names that have an exact value?

Comment: @S.T.A.L.K.E.R , no the first one has value `true`, the second one - `'attribute'`